# DLookUp for Comparing Parameter from one table to another

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

Okay, i know that this question already have answers but nevertheless, i can't seem to make it working! So i need help on this.

here is the lookup code:

```
PH_Stat: DLookUp("[Assumption_Soil_Nutrients_Status]![Status]","Assumption_Soil_Nutrients_Status","Nutrient = 'PH' And [Assumption_Soil_Nutrients_Status]![Placement] = " & [Supportive_Soil_Analysis]![Placement] & " And " & [Supportive_Soil_Analysis]![PH] & " >= [Assumption_Soil_Nutrients_Status]![Min] And " & [Supportive_Soil_Analysis]![PH] & " < [Assumption_Soil_Nutrients_Status]![Max]")
```

The main idea here is to lookup for the value in [Status] column based on this table:

```
Nutrient    Status  Placement   Min   Max
PH          H       IR          5.5   6.5
PH          H       PC          5.5   6.5
PH          L       IR          3.8   4
PH          L       PC          3.8   4
PH          M       IR          4.2   5.5
PH          M       PC          4.2   5.5
PH          ML      IR          4     4.2
PH          ML      PC          4     4.2
PH          VH      IR          6.5   1000
PH          VH      PC          6.5   1000
PH          VL      IR          3.5   3.8
PH          VL      PC          3.5   3.8
PH          XL      IR          0     3.5
PH          XL      PC          0     3.5
CEC         H       IR          18    20
...
```

and here is the record on Supportive_Soil_Analysis table:

```
Sub_Block    Tahun    Placement    PH       CEC
K13          2009     IR           4.7      5.1
```

Can anyone help to point out my mistake? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, anyway.. After giving it another go after a few days, i found the answer to this. Just for anybody who struggling with similar problem, the key here is to add a single apostrophe in between the String Variable (yea it's so obvious that i didn't notice it).

After a fix, here's how it goes:

```
PH_Stat: DLookUp("Status","Assumption_Soil_Nutrients_Status","Nutrient = 'PH' And [Assumption_Soil_Nutrients_Status]![Placement] = '" [Placement] & "' And " & [PH] & " >= [Assumption_Soil_Nutrients_Status]![Min] And " & [PH] & " < [Assumption_Soil_Nutrients_Status]![Max]")
```

And since DLookUp can only use 1 domain (thanks to Chris for pointing this out), we need to create [PH] ad [Placement] column in our query.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are a few issues here:

1. Your 'domain' (to use the `DLookup` jargon) covers two tables yet `DLookup` assumes one - if there's more than one source table, you need to build a query first and use that for the domain.
2. `DLookup` returns a single value to (say) populate a textbox, yet your current code seems to be written wanting to return a set of values to (say) populate a listbox. If your intent is to populate a textbox with a calculated value for the selected record in a form, then the criteria needs to include the primary key value to match to.
3. As you have reported it, it is not clear whether either table actually has a primary key however. *For the sake of a meaningful answer*, I'll assume `Supportive_Soil_Analysis` has an AutoNumber field called `AnalysisID` that serves as the primary key.
4. It is unclear what you are wanting to do when there is more than one record in `Supportive_Soil_Analysis` that has a `PH` within the `Min` and `Max` for a certain `Placement`. E.g., do you want to return multiple rows? Or perhaps you only want one match, picking the one with the highest `PH` if necessary? For simplicity I'll assume the former.

Putting things together, I think you need to create a new query, head immediately into SQL view, and enter code like the following:

```
SELECT Supportive_Soil_Analysis.AnalysisID, Assumption_Soil_Nutrients_Status.Status
FROM Assumption_Soil_Nutrients_Status INNER JOIN Supportive_Soil_Analysis
  ON (Assumption_Soil_Nutrients_Status.Placement = Supportive_Soil_Analysis.Placement)
  AND (Assumption_Soil_Nutrients_Status.PH >= Supportive_Soil_Analysis.[Min]
  AND (Assumption_Soil_Nutrients_Status.PH <= Supportive_Soil_Analysis.[Max])
WHERE Assumption_Soil_Nutrients_Status.Nutrient = 'PH';
```

I've used `<=` not `<` like in your original code because it doesn't make sense for me for `Min` to be inclusive yet `Max` exclusive, though you know your data. That said, if there is a lot of data, it might prove better to do the filtering by `Nutrient` *before* doing the join. This can be done with a second, nested SELECT statement:

```
SELECT Supportive_Soil_Analysis.AnalysisID, Details.Status
FROM (SELECT Status, Placement, [Min], [Max]
      FROM Assumption_Soil_Nutrients_Status
      WHERE Nutrient = 'PH') AS Details INNER JOIN Supportive_Soil_Analysis
  ON (Details.Placement = Supportive_Soil_Analysis.Placement)
  AND (Details.PH >= Supportive_Soil_Analysis.[Min])
  AND (Details.PH <= Supportive_Soil_Analysis.[Max]);
```

In either case, save the query as (say) `Supportive_Soil_Analysis_Status`; the Control Source for the textbox would then be `=DLookup('Status', 'Supportive_Soil_Analysis_Status', 'AnalysisID=' & AnalysisID`. Personally I'd prefer to avoid `DLookup` and set the form on top of another query that aggregates all the displayed data however:

```
SELECT Supportive_Soil_Analysis.*, Supportive_Soil_Analysis_Status.Status
FROM Supportive_Soil_Analysis INNER JOIN Supportive_Soil_Analysis_Status
  ON Supportive_Soil_Analysis.AnalysisID = Supportive_Soil_Analysis_Status.AnalysisID;
```

In this case the Record Source of the form would become what you save this second query as, and Control Source of the text box just `Status`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing them. To make things clearer, first i am making a query with it. Secondly, i just want to populate a column in a query. Third, both table have primary key (composite key), Nutrient, Status, and Placement on Assumption_Soil_Nutrients_Status table; Sub_Block, Tahun, and Placement on Supportive_Soil_Analysis table. Fourth, i just want to return status on a column called PH_Stat inside a query. I can achieve it with Iif, but then problem comes on more complex table so i thought of using DLookUp as an alternative.

Comment: example of output: K13 ; 2009 ; IR ; 4.7 ; (M) with (M) returned by DLookUp Syntax.

Comment: @Milanor - you are making life hard for yourself by not using simple primary keys. I'd add AutoNumber fields and be done with it (you can still convert the existing composite keys into standard composite indices with unique values to maintain data integrity). That said, with respect to `DLookup`, it isn't magic - it's just a shortcut to defining an explicit query or sub-query. As such, if the context is another query not a form, I'd just do it all in SQL.

Comment: Hm, yes you have a point there. The reason why i'm not using simple primary keys is because the Assumption table, once completed will rarely (if not) updated in the future. And i only make those columns as composite key only to prevent duplication. Well, that aside the reason why i want to use DLookUp is because it's too painful to use Iif expression (as there are multiple columns i need, to return the status of each nutrients). And i prefer them to be on one query since i want to show them on 1 report :D

Comment: Another point, i'm using min inclusive and max exclusive because of the ranges setup on my table. Those "max"s overlap the "min"s

Comment: @Milanor - what's your answer to my question 4?

Comment: i wish i can use line breaks in comment, but let me laid out an example of the output (i achieved it with Iif). Header: Placement; PH; PH_Stat; CEC; CEC_Stat. Line 1: IR; 4.7; (M); 18.1; (H). Line 2: IR; 4.6; (M); 18.3; (H)

Comment: May i have your email address? maybe i can pass the database file to you. Easier to explain that way. (Yes i can achieve it with Iif, but since for Leaf analysis there are more parameters and i want to find a simpler workaround for it).

Comment: @Milanor - I'm not giving free email support, sorry.

Comment: lol you get it wrong. I'm not asking for free email support, just to give a clearer picture.